# Unselect radio button list on click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to unselect radio button in radio button list, i know it is more sensible to use checkbox but the management wants radio button to be unchecked.

Comment: `.Checked = false` - Have you really tried anything?..

Comment: Please read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.aspx) and see the [`RadioButton.Checked Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checked.aspx)

Comment: @tnw - Thats documentation for winforms. Its probably [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.aspx)

Comment: @Sayse Ah, didn't see the asp.net tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

RadioButtonList control is a collection of ListItems. To clear one radio button in the control you need to use Index for that particular item. To clear all radio buttons in the control, there is a method "ClearSelection()".

```
  //To Unselect First Item
   RadioButtonList1.Items[0].Selected = false;

  //To unselect all Items
  RadioButtonList1.ClearSelection();
```

hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: I already have used ClearSelection for form reset. User should be allowed to uncheck radio button. I have two options 1.User Active 2.User Inactive.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
RadioButton1.Checked = false;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
private void Clear()
    {
        if(RadioButton1.Checked)
            {
                RadioButton1.Checked = false;
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
myRadioButtonList.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want it to be possible for your radio button group to have zero values selected? Technically, you can just ensure that no radio in the group has its checked value set. `checked=""` or just delete the entire attribute.

Be aware that this is an invalid state for the radio group. It's like a boolean that is set to neither true nor false. It makes no sense semantically and is in violation of the HTML spec.

If you are constrained to a radio group, the only valid option is to include one radio that represents a 'none of the other options' state.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  In my case, I was using the radio button checkedChanged event to automatically append a medical documentation string snippet into a rich text box control.  The snippet would be different for each radio button selected, and the requirement was that only one choice could be allowed.  So radio buttons were the best choice instead of check boxes.  The problem was that if the user wanted to remove ALL of the text snippets from the textbox, the s/he could just manually select the text from the box and delete it -- but at least one radio button would remain selected.

So, I found that the easiest way to fix this would be to add a button to the form and use its _Click event to set the specified radio button checked status to false.

So, My code looked like this...

```
    // for rad 1
    private void rad_NoDifferent_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if(rad_NoDifferent.Checked) {
            rtb_GSC_Notes.AppendText(sRating_NoDiffMsg);
            } else {
            rtb_GSC_Notes.Text = rtb_GSC_Notes.Text.Replace(sRating_NoDiffMsg, sNoMsg.TrimEnd());
            }
        }


    // for rad 2
    private void rad_VeryDifferent_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if(rad_VeryDifferent.Checked) {
            rtb_GSC_Notes.AppendText(sRating_VeryDiffMsg);
            } else {
            rtb_GSC_Notes.Text = rtb_GSC_Notes.Text.Replace(sRating_VeryDiffMsg, sNoMsg.TrimEnd());
            }
        }


    // for rad 3
    private void rad_Unsure_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if(rad_Unsure.Checked) {
            rtb_GSC_Notes.AppendText(sRating_UnsureMsg);
            } else {
            rtb_GSC_Notes.Text = rtb_GSC_Notes.Text.Replace(sRating_UnsureMsg, sNoMsg.TrimEnd());
            }
        }

    // for button reset
    private void btn_ClearRadioButtons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        rad_NoDifferent.Checked = false;
        rad_Unsure.Checked = false;
        rad_VeryDifferent.Checked = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was facing same issue however I found the solution with Radio button.
below are the aspx code for radio button

```
<div>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" GroupName="myg" onClick="clicked(this.id);" runat="server" />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" GroupName="myg" onClick="clicked(this.id);"  runat="server" />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" GroupName="myg" onClick="clicked(this.id);"  runat="server" />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton4" GroupName="myg" onClick="clicked(this.id);"  runat="server" />
</div>
```

Just write below java script.

```
<script type="type/javascript">

var arr = [];

function clicked(radid) {

var ra = document.getElementById(radid);
if (arr.indexOf(radid) < 0) {
    arr.splice(0, arr.length);
    arr.push(radid);
}
else {
    arr.splice(0, arr.length);
    ra.checked = false;

}
}
</script>
```

Hope this will solve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

**WPF/C#**

```
if (RadioBTN.IsChecked == true) {
    RadioBTN.IsChecked = false;
}
```